# How to get business visa extension in Spain

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, europe, spain, visa-extensions

I am from India and I came to Spain for business meetings. My plan was to stay for one month [but found out the business will be closed for one week for Christmas]. My visa is valid from 2nd December 2016 to 15 January 2017; the duration of stay is 30 days. I arrived in Barcelona on the 4th of December, per the visa, and I planned to leave by the 4th of January. I want to extend the stay until the 14th of January.

How do I apply for a visa extension? Is it actually necessary to apply for an extension since I am leaving before the expiry date on the visa (15 January)?

[image]

Comment: Length of stay and validity are two different things. Since your visa is a multiple-entry visa, what you are allowed to do is leave now and come back in January. That way you can use the remainder of your 30 days at the beginning of January. You cannot stay longer than 30 days even if the validity period is longer and I don't think you would qualify for an extension in this situation.

Comment: @Dorothy I'm afraid you might have changed the meaning of the question. I suspect the Sunil didn't plan to leave for Christmas but he found out that the office where he is working is closed, which is why he needs to stay longer.

Comment: @Relaxed I struggled with that; I'll adjust thx

Comment: I agree with @Relaxed you should go back home now and ask the cognisant issuer for an extension.  Your premise is **solid gold** and they will surely agree to a variance, not to mention the good faith demonstrated.  I propose Relaxed or Dorothy write it up!